# Empty body with express api that raises error when bcryptjs

Tags: node.js, api, express, body-parser

my goal is to make an authentification system with express api (used with angular frontend)
A few hours ago, i've got a problem while creating the front-end : 
the api raised some errors when hashing password in the code :

```
            const name = req.body.name;
            const email = req.body.email;
            const password = bcrypt.hashSync(String(req.body.password));
            console.log(req.body);
            usermodel.createUser([name, email, password], (err) => {
                try {
                    if (err) return res.json({
                        success: false,
                        message: err.toString(),
                    });
                    usermodel.findUserByEmail(email, (err, user) => {
                        if (err) return res.json({
                            success: false,
                            message: 'Server error! '
                        });
                        console.log(user);
                        const expiresIn = 24 * 60 * 60;
                        const accessToken = jwt.sign({
                            id: user.id
                        }, config.secret, {
                            expiresIn: expiresIn
                        });
                        res.json({
                            success: true,
                            "user": user,
                            "access_token": accessToken,
                            "expires_in": expiresIn
                        });
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    res.json({success: false, message:error.toString()})
                }
```

After a few modifications, it seems that the body is empty even when I put some parameters :

```
app.post('/ping', function(req, res) {
  console.log('trigerred')
  res.json({body: req.body});
});
```

--> undefined :(
I already had the problem, it was because my express api wasn't https with postman, so I made it https.
I verified bodyparser:

```
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Any idea why the body is empty ? Thanks ^^ 
PS: it's strange, because it was working a few hours ago

Comment: can you share your api request

Comment: What does `console.log(req.body)` output in the console if you put it before the hashing?

Comment: Anyway, with curl, or postman, or request from frontend, the body of ping command = {}